# How to create a slidein menu which slides from right to left in which slidein menu covers other part of screen?

Tags: android

I have to create a slidein menu from left to right and also the menu needs to slide on click of a button and not on swipe.

The menu should also cover the other part of the screen and should not slide the other part of the screen.

Comment: The menu should open on click of the button and not upon sliding?

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer, which mekes it possible for you to slide from any side.

Answer (score 2):

use this https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu sliding menu libray.

to cover the other part use [navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

or [sliding layer](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/sliding-layer)

Comment: In this github exmaple the menu slides the other menu. According to my requirement upon click of button the menu should overlap(cover) other fragment.

Comment: if i try sliding layer in developer.android.com no class is being shown. Can you exactly specify the class to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new pattern called [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)?

Or you can create a RelativeLayout and put its visibility to GONE on the onCreate method of the Action.
Then override the method onTouch like:

```
@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : {
        startY = event.getY();
        break ;           
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        float endY = event.getY();

        if (endY < startY) {
            System.out.println("Move UP");
            ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else {
            ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
return true;
}
```

If you want to add some animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%"
            android:toYDelta="40%"
            android:duration="400"/>

</set>
```

and start the animation in the onTouch method.
I've a post in my blog where you can find more information. Look [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/11/android-sliding-menu-animation.html)

Comment: Thank you JFrankie. I will try Navigation Drawer.